# Multi-column comment

Tags: sql, oracle

I know that I can comment a column with `COMMENT ON COLUMN table.column IS 'commentString'`, but is there a way to add the same comment to more than one column in one statement?

For example, I need to add the comment "User Data" to columns NAME and BIRTHDATE and I'd like to understand if it's possible to do it in one statement, instead of repeating `COMMENT ON COLUMN x.y IS 'User Data'` two times.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. And it kinda defeats the purpose, since the comment should explain something about the column. Name and Birthday are probably in the user table, so it's obvious that they are user data. If it's not a user table, than maybe you need to reconsider your data model, or at least consider renaming them to USERNAME and USERBIRTHDAY.

Comment: I agree with your logic, but unfortunately it doesn't depend on me!

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid you have to copy the statement. `Comment on column` applies a comment to just one column.

Comment: as @GolezTrol said it is impossible in straight way, but you can do it with dynamic SQL in PL\SQL block i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible in straight way, but you can do it with dynamic SQL in PL\SQL block

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT t.owner || '.' || t.table_name || '.' || t.column_name col
                FROM all_tab_cols t
               WHERE t.owner = 'OWNER' AND t.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME' AND
                     t.column_name IN ('COL1', 'COL2'))
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'COMMENT ON COLUMN ' || i.col ||
                          ' IS ''PLACE COMMENT HERE''';
    END LOOP;
END;
```